# Regular expression for find "contact" page url on web-site

Tags: regex

i am newer in regular expressions. How can I write regular expression for this:
we have domain like "example.com" and we need to find all expressions like:

```
'example.com/contacts'
"example.com/lalalae2t348og7bc/contacts"
'example.com/contacts.html'
"example.com/1/2/3/4/4/5/6/6/6/6/contact-faq.php"
etc
```

Please help.

Comment: (testlol.ru*/[a-z-.]+) this work for testlol.ru/lal-contact.php

Comment: works: (example.ru*[./a-z0-9-]+)

Comment: itog: $regexp = "(".$domain."[./a-z0-9-]+(contact)[./a-z0-9-]+)";

Comment: (example.com[./a-z0-9-]+(contact)[./a-z0-9-]+)

Answer (score 2):

Try this to receive the contact page link. It worked for me.

```
/<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?contact.*?)\"[^>]*>(.*)?<\/a>/
```

It worked for me for these codes:

```
<a href="contacts" class="sdf" target="_blank">Contact</a>
<a href="lalalae2t348og7bc/contacts" class="sdf" 
target="_blank">Contact</a>
<a href="contacts.html" class="sdf" target="_blank">Contact</a>
<a href="1/2/3/4/4/5/6/6/6/6/contact-faq.php" class="sdf" target="_blank">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the answer:

```
 example.com[./a-z0-9-]+(contact)[./a-z0-9-]+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
^example\.com
```

this regex will test if the string is starting with example.com